# Verify my interpretation of this python code snippet is correct

Tags: python, code-snippets

I'm analyzing a set of python scripts and came across this snippet.  I'm not sure if my interpretation is correct, since I haven't come across any similar C or Java code and I don't know Python.

```
for i in xrange(self.num_sections):
        offset, a1,a2,a3,a4 = struct.unpack('>LBBBB', self.data_file[78+i*8:78+i*8+8])
        flags, val = a1, a2<<16|a3<<8|a4
        self.sections.append( (offset, flags, val) )
```

My interpretation goes like this:

```
for each item in num_sections
  convert the data_file range into a big-endian unsigned long, and 4 unsigned char
  insert unpacked values into offset, a1, a2, a3 and a4 variables

  set flags to = a1
  set val to a2 shifted left 16 bits then OR'd with a3 shifted right 8 bits 
  then OR'd with a4
```

Essentially, I think the original unpack operation extracts 8 bytes, dumps 4 of them as an unsigned long, then adds the rest in sequential order to the a* variables.

Comment: That seems perfectly correct (except for a typo? a3 is shifted left, not right).

Comment: Looks right to me. Except for the left/right thing that @NiklasB. found.

Comment: yup.  so it's basically a 4 byte int, a byte, and a 3 byte int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.